# Do Docker multi-arch images have the same image ID for each arch?

Tags: docker

Do Docker multi-arch images have the same image ID (not Docker Content Digest! Image ID!) for each arch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For images built from the same Dockerfile and base image but with different architectures, no.

For example with [`httpd:2.4.43-alpine`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/httpd/library/httpd/2.4.43-alpine/images/sha256-fc11fbd1bc066776c608d2dddc6eafd1f6848ba709b452a6fa5d806fb13dd0f6?context=explore), you can pull tags for different architecture:

```
# linux/amd64
docker pull httpd:2.4.43-alpine@sha256:fc11fbd1bc066776c608d2dddc6eafd1f6848ba709b452a6fa5d806fb13dd0f6

# linux/386
docker pull httpd:2.4.43-alpine@sha256:580d279181c20f105a9ef8bea9b1dac221d03f524b17d4a0b5bc7ea0c2be7a38
```

They do have a different ID:

```
docker image inspect httpd:2.4.43-alpine@sha256:fc11fbd1bc066776c608d2dddc6eafd1f6848ba709b452a6fa5d806fb13dd0f6 -f '{{ .Id }}'
# sha256:e7e8868c76974de9e867a76ccb25afd4415b313c2db3bdda7f92a789e3b5b6ae

docker image inspect httpd:2.4.43-alpine@sha256:580d279181c20f105a9ef8bea9b1dac221d03f524b17d4a0b5bc7ea0c2be7a38 -f '{{ .Id }}'
# sha256:a25ba4ab8022a688ef0c1d7d9c6c7e8cd15c769213bdef660a598fe46d07b889
```